# Getting PyEphem to return angles with sign

Tags: python, pyephem

How do I get PyEphem to give angles with sign and a zero padded to degrees. Currently it returns 2:46:32.8 but I want it in the form +02:46:32.8.
Now, I could define a function to return it in that form, but I was wondering if there was a simpler way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the underlying C code inside of `libastro` does not support leading plus signs or leading zeros. You will have to write a little Python function of your own to add them.